# check if a program is already installed

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to check whether a program like firefox exists on ubuntu or not. **In case it is not installed, I want to install it.** I studied this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) and got information about `command -v p programName`, but I didn't understand how can I check if the program is installed or not. I want to write this:

```
#If firefox not installed:
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt install firefox
```

but I don't know how to write the **if condition** part.

Comment: You can follow the steps given here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1103874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if ! command -v firefox >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt install firefox
fi
```

Also notice that not all Linux systems use apt-get and that if sudo is
configured to request a password the script will stall and wait for
user to type a password which might be confusing.

Comment: I'm supposed to use it on Ubuntu. So should I use an alternative for "apt-get"? But I think it is not possible to use these commands without sudo, yes?

Comment: If you're going to use only on Ubuntu-based distros then it's ok. It's not about `sudo`, you need to be root.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to give the root access at the beginning of the code, so that each time the script will not stall and wait for user to type a password? or at least one time it asks for the password.

Comment: You can run the entire script with sudo: `sudo ./script.sh`